# PayPal redirect issue on Wix Platform

Tags: paypal

I am creating a website for the charity that I work for (which has a very limited budget, and we therefore are making use of me (a social worker who happens to be okay at some computer stuff) and a developer friend) on the Wix platform.  The purpose of the website is to safely host profiles of children and youth available for adoption across Canada, and as a result there are two levels of access to the site:

- public access, where the profiles contain no identifying information, no pictures and make use of a pseudonym
- private profiles of waiting children and youth can only be viewed by potential adoptive parent(s) who have been approved for access. In order to be approved, a processing fee of $75.00 must be paid, and the following documents must be submitted: current, approved home study, vulnerable sector check, PRIDE training certificate (or provincial/territorial equivalent) and a Potential Adoptive Parent(s) Profile. (I do have one page where this all sits)

The privately accessible profiles contain further information about the child or youth, including their age, background, abilities, conditions, hobbies and interests, as well as as a pictures and the first name of the profiles child/youth.

The issue that I am running into is that it is not possible to direct people to a specific page of the Wix site after they have completed the PayPal purchase. In addition, there is no email notification for when a customer purchases a plan (even though a confirmation email is sent to the customer, which is not possible to customize, which is absolutely maddening, but whatever).

I have set the requirement 'People I approve' for the Private Child & Youth Profiles as a workaround for protecting the privacy of the children and youth, but I really have no idea how to best automate this process.

I have sent a ticket request to Wix support, and received an unsatisfactory answer (which was basically that it wasn't possible to direct them to a specific page of the site from PayPal after completing the purchase, even though on PayPal, it literally says that you can)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with Wix before, but I maybe able to point you in the right direction.

According to the Wix forum, there is a post detailing [Paypal button Post-Action](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/paypal-button-post-action)

> What you can do is use a custom coded PayPal button. This will allow PayPal to send a success message back to the page if the payment was successfull, and then, you can construct a unique link related to that user with page code and email that custom link to the client..
>   It will be quite a process to make it work, you will need custom PayPal integration, custom sendgrid email integration and a clever bit of code..